# Remove numbers from a list of strings

Tags: r, design-patterns

I have a list of strings like this

```
string_list<-c(">=23", ">=50", "large than 23 years", "Yes", "No2", "Yes4", "Negative", "Positive9", "Negative10")
```

Is there a way to remove the numbers after Yes, No, Positive, and Negative while not affecting the rest of the string? I used string_remove but I can't identify this specific pattern. Here is the list I wanted to have:

```
string_list<-c(">=23", ">=50", "large than 23 years", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
string_list<-c(">=23", ">=50", "large than 23 years", "Yes", "No2", "Yes4", "Negative", "Positive9", "Negative10")
gsub("(?i)(yes|no|positive|negative)[0-9]+","\\1", string_list)
#> [1] ">=23"                ">=50"                "large than 23 years"
#> [4] "Yes"                 "No"                  "Yes"                
#> [7] "Negative"            "Positive"            "Negative"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, which searches for the specific strings and removes the numbers. Note if case may be an issue in your real data (i.e. Yes, yes) use `ignore.case = TRUE`:

```
string_list[grep("Yes|No|Posi|Neg", string_list)] <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', string_list[grep("Yes|No|Posi|Neg", string_list)])
```

Output:

```
# [1] ">=23"                ">=50"                "large than 23 years"
# [4] "Yes"                 "No"                  "Yes"                
# [7] "Negative"            "Positive"           "Negative"
```